# Store grid position on server side

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm storing the grid column positions, width,.. in cookie with session manager:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
  expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*7))
}));
```

And on grid, I have set the property to:

```
stateful: true
```

It works ok. But the problem is, that this data is stored in client cookie. When opening the same page with different browsers the position is not maintained.

How could I store this data on server side and then send it to client when needed?
Any example?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, we are currently doing it now on our webserver.  This gist of it is we store the json string state that would have been persisted on the cookie in our server's persistence layer.  When the page is being built on the server it embeds the json data for the associated user in the page.  The client code then uses our defined provider which inherits from `Ext.state.Provider` which along with lots of other stuff it reads the embedded json data to set the states.